# Why after running subprocess.Popen(), not able to write to a file?

Tags: redhat, cron, python

I am not able to write to a file after

```
> Popen() runs

conf_file='/home/'+ service_ac +'/conf/keep-allGateways-alive.cfg'

def find_gw_ips():
        fp=open(conf_file,'w')
        fp.write('hello') #this gets printed in file
        t = subprocess.Popen("ifconfig", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        result=t.stdout.read()
        fp.write('hello_2') #this does not get printed in file

find_gw_ips()
```

I use crontab to run this script, without crontab it runs good, without any issues

```
* * * * * python /home/vtu/bin/script.py vtu >/tmp/out.txt 2>&1
```

I am using RHEL 7.4, python 2.7.5

I tried redirecting and got errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vru/bin/keep-allGateways-alive.py", line 34, in <module>
    find_gw_ips()
  File "/home/vru/bin/keep-allGateways-alive.py", line 30, in find_gw_ips
    t = subprocess.Popen("ifconfig", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try using the full path to *ifconfig*. Jobs run from *cron* often have very different PATHs set.

Comment: Joel C, thxx expert, that resolves it, awsm.
but, I used one more command "subprocess.call(["ping", "-c", "1","someIP"]), how this runs without full path everytime.